# pythonで単回帰分析を行いたい

Tags: python, csv

pythonのjupyterのnotebookで単回帰分析を行いたいのですが、データの一つがdf1として保存できているのですが、もう一方のx軸に当たる部分のｃｓｖが保存されていないので[1,2,3,........]として単回帰分析を行いたいのですが方法がわかりません。。

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(x,y1)
```

```
Name Error                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-bc6b4eab4f87> in <module>
     2
     3 lr = LinearRegression()
----> 4 lr.fit(x,y1)

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

xに当たる部分をどう作ればいいかがわかりません。

[image]

Comment: この場合、説明変数(explanatory variable)には df.index を使うしかないでしょうね(意味のある回帰分析にならないと思いますが)……

Answer (score 1):

エラーは、xが定義されていないことを示しています。 fitの前にXを定義する必要があります（Xに割り当てられたデータフレームであるセルを実行します）